# SQL Query to select data from two tables with single column known

Tags: sql

I have a table named alumnidetails with columns(username,firstname,mobile,email) and another table alumwork with columns(username,work,course,branch). Now i want to select data from both tables. I have only firstname value. What is the sql query. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    alumnidetails ad
INNER JOIN alumwork aw
    ON ad.username = aw.username
WHERE
    ad.firstname = ‘Pete’;
```

By the way, it's uncommon to connect two tables using strings (username, in your case). It's way slower than using id's. You could add an 'id' column your alumnidetails table, and a 'alumnidetails_id' column in your alumwork table.

Your naming is inconsistent too, by the way. And that's gonna annoy someone at some point.